# Is there a nicer way to connect Scan and Broadcast in Akka Stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Let's assume I want to create a `Flow`, which takes `Int`s and outputs tuples `(doubled int, sum)`. So I fan-out ints, `map` on one edge and `scan` on the other. Then I `zip` them and this is the result:

```
object Main extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val flow = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
    val zip = b.add(Zip[Int, Int])

    val flowMap = b.add(Flow[Int].map(_ * 2))
    val flowScan = b.add(Flow[Int].scan(0)(_ + _))

    broadcast.out(0) ~> flowMap ~> zip.in0
    broadcast.out(1) ~> flowScan ~> zip.in1

    FlowShape(broadcast.in, zip.out)
  })

  Source(1 to 5).via(flow).to(Sink.foreach(println)).run()
}
```

**Unfortunately, this doesn't output anything.** I researched it a bit and found out that:

- `Broadcast` emits when all of the outputs stop backpressuring and there is an input element available,
- `Scan` backpressures when downstream backpressures.

This makes the whole flow deadlock and nothing happens. Does somebody know how to achieve the result:

```
(2,0)
(4,1)
(6,3)
(8,6)
(10,10)
```

in a nice way? The only solution I have found so far is to use `.buffer`:

```
val flowScan = b.add(Flow[Int].buffer(1, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).scan(0)(_ + _))
```

But I don't really like this solution because it is describing not only the logic, but also some technicalities...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the deadlock is that scan will upon its first demand, emit the start value, so `0` in this case and not pass demand upstream, this means that demand only reaches `broadcast.out(0)` and as you said, `broadcast` only emits when there has been demand from all the downstreams.

The buffer might seem like a technicality, but it is actually expressing the graph according to what you want to achieve, that you want to zip the two branches, but the scan-one will always be one element ahead of the other. This is very central to how akka-streams works.

So your result is not actually something that matches what broadcast+zip does without some additional graph nodes, I think that the way to most cleanly express what you want to happen is to place the buffer separately before the scan, this makes it more clear that one branch will be ahead of the other:

```
  broadcast.out(0) ~>       flowMap      ~> zip.in0
  broadcast.out(1) ~> buffer ~> flowScan ~> zip.in1
```